# Adding annotations to all querysets with a custom QuerySet as Manager

Tags: django, django-models

I'm not sure how to put words on this precisely, but what I'm trying to do is use a custom `QuerySet` for a model, but I want to annotate the results of any queryset. So whether filters were applied, or it was a direct `get` of an object (which I think is still a `filter()` call in the end), I want the annotations to be applied so I can access them in the `Model` objects I get back.

My current solution is using a custom `QuerySet` + custom Manager, and the custom `Manager` passes custom calls off to the appropriate call on the custom `QuerySet`. Of course, this has the unfortunate need to match methods between the manager and queryset for any custom method I want.

I know that `CustomQuerySet.as_manager()` exists to avoid this duplication, but if I use that, then I lose the ability to override `get_queryset()` so my annotations can be applied in all cases of evaluating a queryset.

Is there a cleaner way to do this so I am still left with the ability to chain calls and have my annotations apply when the queryset is finally evaluated?

Ideally I'd like to keep using standard calls like:
`Model.objects.most_liked().near()`
and
`Model.objects.get(id=model_id)`

As opposed to having to do something like add an add_annotations() method to my custom QuerySet, thereby needing to always call that method anytime I get Model objects (ie. I don't want `Model.objects.get(id=id).add_annotations()` and `Model.objects.near().add_annotations()` and so on)

but not have to repeat the methods between manager and queryset? Ideally without hacking into private methods or anything like that. I briefly toyed with overriding `__iter__` on the CustomQuerySet class to add the annotations then, but it didn't seem right to do that.

Sample setup of model, queryset, and manager below. These of course aren't my real class names, just fillers for the question. Hopefully I've included enough to make my question understandable :)

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def most_liked(self):
        return self.filter(...)

    def near(self): 
        return self.filter(...)


class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)\
            .annotate(...)\
            .annotate(...)

    def near(self, latitude, longitude, radius, max_results=100):
        return self.get_queryset().near()

    def most_liked(self):
        return self.get_queryset().most_liked()

class Model(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the [`from_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset) method - it allows you to create a Manager class which you can further customise before applying to your model. For example:

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def most_liked(self):
        return self.filter(...)


class CustomManager(models.Manager.from_queryset(CustomQuerySet)):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CustomManager, self).get_queryset() \
            .annotate(...)


class Model(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! 

Though I left the get_queryset() method as:
`def get_queryset(self):
    return CustomQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)\
        .annotate(...)\
        .annotate(...)`

The change you had made led to infinite recursion. Was there something I'm doing wrong though in get_queryset() by doing it as I have above?

Comment: Hmm, I made a typo (missing bracket) - does that work for you now?

Comment: It does, indeed. And makes more sense than what I was doing there, as well. My brain got a bit warped by all the things I tried to get it going before your help. Thank you very much!