# Django: When to use model fields and when to use reverse queries.

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a question regarding best practices with Django models. I have webscraper running that indexes both 'Ads', 'Sellers' and 'Searches'.

A (simplified) representation of these models would look like this:

```
class Search(models.Model):
   date: models.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)


class Seller(models.Model):
   name: models.CharField(max_length=500)
   profile_url: models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Ad(models.Model):
   title: models.CharField(max_length=500)
   price: models.FloatField()
   seller: models.Foreignkey(Seller, related_name='ads')
   found_in: models.Foreignkey(Search, related_name='ads')
```

I'm currently creating detailview for these different models that each display statistical information. For the 'Seller' model I would like to show 'total ads',  'average price' and 'median price' attributes, and for the search I would like to display these as well.

What I am wondering is how I should get that data. I could do it by a reverse query (Seller.ads, etc), or I could create a new field on the Seller model that is set after each scraping operation.

It seems somewhat silly to set these fields that can be easily retrieved with a simple query, but this database is probably going to reach tens of thousands of lines, so it might get slower in the long run. I am basically wondering what the best practices are, and if there is a somewhat specific 'cut of point' between retrieving information via a database query vs setting the information on a modelfield and getting it from there.

Comment: Tens of thousands of records isn't much at all. I wouldn't start worrying about denormalizing to improve performance until you actually start to notice a performance issue, and at that point, you might want to look into creating indexes or using other techniques before denormalizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, Sums and Average to annotate your seller query. Median is a bit trickier, you can do it yourself or you can use [django-extra-tools](https://github.com/tomi77/django-extra-tools) which supplies an aggregation function.

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum
from django_extra_tools.db.models.aggregates import Median

sellers_annotated = Seller.objects.all().annotate(
    total_ads = Count('ads')
  ).annotate(
    average_price = Average('ads__price')
  ).annotate(
    median_price = Median('ads__price')
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Am I correct in understanding that you would not add fields to the models instead?

Comment: I would avoid adding fields that are subject to change on other fields. If you need to access this in multiple places the best thing to do would be to implement a Manager class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519663/adding-annotations-to-all-querysets-with-a-custom-queryset-as-manager)