# Include a django model object property using annotate()

Tags: django, properties, model, django-queryset, annotate

I have a model that includes a `@property` that I want included when I do things like

`vals = MyModel.objects.values()`

[Another S/O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519663/adding-annotations-to-all-querysets-with-a-custom-queryset-as-manager?rq=1) suggests the way to do this is by overriding the `get_queryset` method of a manager class, augmented with a call to `annotate(xtra_field=...)`.

The problem is I can find no example of how to do this with a model property.   I have tried things like

`super(SuperClass, self).get_queryset().annotate(xtra_fld=self.model.xtra_prop)`

and numerous variations thereof, none of which work.

The question, I think is What should the RHS of the annotation argument(s) be?

(And, yes, I know there are other, clunkier ways to do this, like iterating over what `values()` returns and adding the property as I go.   Just not a very elegant (or even django) solution, to me.

Comment: You can not do that for a `@property`, since properties are at the Python level. The database does not know anything about the properties.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense now that I think about it.  On further research, I think the solution will be to create a custom field that can construct/deconstruct the actual db field.  What I'm doing is not unlike the ``Hand`` example in the docu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you're generating the property value in the database, you can't do this without overriding django's internal methods – **which I recommend against**.

A more elegant solution might be to add an extra method to [a custom queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/) which generates the extra field on request:

```
from django.db import models

class AreaQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def values_with_area(self, *fields):
        # width & height are always required to calculate the area
        fields = set(fields)
        fields.update(['width', 'height'])

        for row in self.values(*fields):
            row['area'] = Widget.calculate_area(row['width'], row['height'])
            yield row

class Widget(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = AreaQuerySet.as_manager()

    @classmethod
    def calculate_area(cls, width, height):
        return width * height

    @property
    def area(self):
        return Widget.calculate_area(self.width, self.height)
```

Comment: I think you meant to reference AreaQuerySet as manager in Widgets model.

Comment: Something like this might work.  But, I feel like this is a more involved solution.  I'm hoping it's some kind of semantic like the double underscore.  To wit:  ``...annotate(xtra_field='self__xtraproperty')``.  It *should* be that simple.